Autodesk Tandem REST API forbidden
I had a problem retrieving the documents and streams of my building model on Autodesk tandem using the tutorial rest sample below.(https://github.com/autodesk-tandem/tutorial-rest). The original guide on github mentioned that I need to add the Client ID to a service tab, but in this new updated Tandem, the service tab seem to be removed. In the code below, I use the ClientID and secret from the APS portal, and the account is also the owner of the building model on Tandem. But when I tried to to the GET request, I've always got { title: 'Forbidden', detail: 'Forbidden' } for the documents and streams. I've managed to print out the tokens, so there shouldn't be a problem with my account, the scope is set to "data:read". I did tried the TestBed App for Javascript and REST and both are working fine with my account.
Please let me know which authentication step I'm missing here in this code.
Thank you
Figure 1

Figure 2


there was recently change in Tandem UI - use Add API Key to enter Client ID of your APS App. Also make sure to specify correct permission (i.e. Edit or Manage) to make sure that app can update facility data.
